# How to remove HTML tags from output text?

Tags: python, html

Apologies if this question has already been asked before, but all the solutions I have tried did not seem to work.

I have created a program where the user enters a word, and the program pulls an example of that word from the Dictionary.com website.

I want to remove the HTML tags that always surround the keyword. How would I go about doing this?

```
import requests

word = input("Enter a word: ")

webContent = requests.get('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/'+word)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(webContent.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7'})

firstResult = results[0]
print(firstResult.contents[0:3])
```

Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: There is an unix command line utility for that: html2text. 
So you can pipe like so: `./myprog > html2text` to output text https://linux.die.net/man/1/html2text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
import re

word = input("Enter a word: ")

webContent = requests.get('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/'+word)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(webContent.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7'})

firstResult = results[0]
firstResult.contents=[re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', str(x)) for x in firstResult.contents]
print(firstResult.contents[0:3])
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this: you just need to use the .getText() function

```
import requests
word = input("Enter a word: ")
webContent = requests.get('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/'+word)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(webContent.text, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find_all('p', attrs={'class':'one-click-content css-it69we e15kc6du7'})

result = soup.find('p').getText()
print(result)
```